# Making a game preloader (Flash)

Tags: flash, loading, swf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you create a single/internal pre-loader for a Flash game written using Flex?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/how-do-you-create-a-single-internal-pre-loader-for-a-flash-game-written-using-fle)

Hi guys, Im trying to make a preloader in a Flash game.

Thing is, I need some advices on this since I never made one, I have the game almost complete, but when, i.e, I upload the game to a website I get a white screen for a few seconds, and then I see the game.

Is there a simple way, maybe using an a API or something like that, to make a preloader screen?

Im using Flash Builder fyi.

Thx!

Comment: Bummzack's recommendation will get you your answers, especially the AS3-only, non-Flex answer.

Comment: Hm the comment (recommendation) was automatically removed when the question was closed. It was the link that is now on top of this question.